# Tango With Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'registration'

Tags: python, linux, django

I have cloned [this](https://github.com/leifos/tango_with_django_19) repository as part of a tutorial and gone into the directory `tango_with_django_19/code/tango_with_django_project` to run the command:

```
$ python maange.py runserver
```

In order to run the web app.  However, I received the following errors:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f6e2c1782f0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'registration'
```

I am using Manjaro Linux and have installed the packages `python-django` and `python-django-extensions` with pacman.

How can I resolve this error so that I can run the web app?  I have not changed after cloning the aforementioned repo.

Comment: Have you installed the packages in the requirements file and ran a migration?

Comment: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @Bernard Parah No, I haven't.  I'll try to figure out how to do that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the project dependencies.

run `pip install -r requirements.txt` in tango_with_django_19/code to install them.

Then migrate and runserver

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `django-registration-redux` package. It is specified in [`requirements.txt`](https://github.com/leifos/tango_with_django_19/blob/master/code/requirements.txt) file as necessary to run project. You could install it via `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

if you get the error after `pip install django-registration-redux` you can try `easy_install django-registration-redux` it worked for me.